# Posterior for Beta in Linear Regression

Tags: normal-distribution, bayesian, linear-regression

We are given a simple linear regression model, $y_i$ = $\beta$$x_i$ + $\epsilon$$_i$ and $\epsilon$$_i$ ~ N(0, 1). We are then asked to calculate the likelihood of the model in terms of $\beta$. I was able to solve that.

We are then told the prior for $\beta$ is N(0,100). We are asked to find the posterior distribution of $\beta$ given a dataset. I found:

$P(\beta | x, y)$ $\propto$ $\exp\left[\sum \left(- \frac{{(y_i - \beta x_i)^2}}{2}\right) - \frac{{\beta^2}}{200}\right]$. I know this is going to be a normal distribution. However, I want to simplify it as N($\mu$, $\sigma^2$) but I am not being able to find the values of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.

Can someone help me to find the simplified posterior distribution of $\beta$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could "complete the square" inside the $[\,]$

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Henry, I tried doing that but couldn't reach a proper solution. Could you maybe show me how I could reach one?

Comment: You expand the $\sum \left(- \frac{{(y_i - \beta x_i)^2}}{2}\right) - \frac{{\beta^2}}{200}$ and rearrange to get something that looks like $ -\frac{\beta^2 -2u \beta +v}{2w}$ for suitable $u,v,w$ and then write this as $-\frac{(\beta-u)^2}{2w} +\frac{u^2-v}{2w}$ where the second term is in effect a constant as far as $\beta$ is concerned and can be taken outside the exponential (and goes into the proportionality)

Comment: *Hint*: it is easier to use [precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_(statistics)) instead of variance in Bayesian analysis involving normal distributions.

Comment: @Henry but how do I get rid of the xi term?

Comment: The $x_i$ terms will appear in $w$ (and in $v$ and $u$).  Something like $(\beta x_1)^2 +(\beta x_2)^2 = \beta^2(x_1^2+x_2^2) = \dfrac{\beta^2}{\frac1{x_1^2+x_2^2}}$

Comment: @Henry could you kindly try solving it please? I am just not getting it

Comment: It looks possible but some effort - so no - it is your exercise and you need to do it.